# Fall into favour

Tags: expressions

I am writing a university personal statement and would like to use the expression "fall into favour of recruiters" to express my desire of being well rated in the job market once I graduate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression 'fall out of favour' is idiomatic, but 'fall into favour' is not.

You could say 'find the favour' instead, but I suggest you follow the advice of @Richard Sole and find some safer expression. I might use  'gain the approval'.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you want to use **fall into favour** is not idiomatic. (No instances of it can be found on Google Books Ngram Viewer, for instance.)

It appears to be a deliberate play on the well-established opposite phrase **to fall out of favour**.

While it's probable that people reading your personal statement will understand what you are trying to say, they may well conclude that you don't have a good grasp of English idiom.

It might be safer to stick to a construction such as **to impress recruiters** or **to make a positive impression on recruiters**.

Comment: It's used, but rarely.  It's a 19th century phrase with only vestigial use nowadays. I agree with your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you want I don't understand.But if you use proper way "fall into favour of recruiters" you can see my example.May be it's help to you.

1. I remember there was a terrible storm before the start and it fell into our 
   favour as we had all the big bombers in our team.
2. Most striking is Britney, who explodes into fame in 1999 and almost as 
   swiftly falls from favour again: Courtney is another.
3. These ideas took a circuitous route into favour.